# Mqtt Node Js deploying on heroku crashes

Tags: node.js, heroku, port, mqtt

I am working on an IoT project. I am going to use Mqtt for communication between devices, I started running simple example using NodeJs and [mosca](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) and it's running on my local linux machine.

When I started deploying over Heroku I faced a crash problem.

here's my code:

```
var mosca = require('mosca')
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var sys = require('sys');

var settings = {
  port: 1883 || Number(process.env.PORT)
};

//here we start mosca
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}

// fired whena  client is connected
server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published : ', packet.payload);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client is disconnecting
server.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

// fired when a client is disconnected
server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});
```

and this is the crash reported by heroku logs:

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-28T12:49:43.209288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with      command `node index.js`
2015-09-28T12:49:48.669918+00:00 app[web.1]: (node) sys is deprecated.  Use util instead.
2015-09-28T12:49:48.718428+00:00 app[web.1]: Mosca server is up and  running
2015-09-28T12:50:43.468112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of  launch
2015-09-28T12:50:43.468112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-28T12:50:44.373307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-28T12:50:44.352908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-28T12:53:30.899810+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-28T12:53:30.899837+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-28T12:53:30.830161+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c237cb9 by mstfkhattab@gmail.com
2015-09-28T12:53:30.830200+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v20 created by mstfkhattab@gmail.com
2015-09-28T12:53:30.926174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-28T12:53:33.726073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2015-09-28T12:53:36.600467+00:00 app[web.1]: (node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
2015-09-28T12:53:36.643097+00:00 app[web.1]: Mosca server is up and running
2015-09-28T12:54:33.858449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-09-28T12:54:33.858449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-28T12:54:34.801910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-28T12:54:34.781887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-28T12:54:36.720413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iot-mqtt-glinty-tutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=b74f96e4-0a38-405d-a3c6-38fd41c601b0 fwd="196.221.206.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-28T12:54:37.904668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=iot-mqtt-glinty-tutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=19d27d3a-a478-47a0-8e3f-532d741d15ac fwd="196.221.206.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any solution to that please ???

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because it's expecting a web process to bind to `process.env.PORT`, but there is no such process. You include the `http` module but never use it. By default, Heroku expects there to be some sort of web service running.

If this application doesn't have a web process (shouldn't listen on a port) then you should create a `Procfile` and specify how you would like to start it, eg:

```
server: node server.js
```

More info on Procfiles:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: It seems that the Procfile plays a great role in heroku, but the problem is that heroku is always searching for default http/webservice in the index file

Comment: Heroku doesn't consider 'index' to be anything special. The only special thing is the assumption of a 'web' service in the absence of a Procfile. Without indicating to Heroku how to start the process you want to start, what else would Heroku do to start your app? ie, if you don't tell Heroku how to start your app, what do you expect the app launching system to do?